# PyQT executable file crashes but works fine in python console

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pyqt5, exe, executable

I created an application using PyQT5 that loads an image of MNIST using the Load button. Then this application can load a trained Keras model on MNIST in h5 format. The trained model is loaded using the Classify button, and the loaded model predicts the input image. Finally, the predicted class and its corresponding probability can be saved to the directory. This app works fine before packaging and converting to an executable file, but while running on the Python console, there is neither warning nor an error. After making the file executable using the "Pyinstaller" package, in the second stage, just after pressing the "Classify" button, which is connected to the "Classify_Image" function, the app crashes and does not work anymore.
My code is accessible for additional examination below.

```
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 340)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 318, 291))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.Load = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.Load.setObjectName("Load")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Load)
        #########################################################
        self.Load.setEnabled(True)
        self.Load.clicked.connect(self.Load_Image)
        #########################################################
        self.Classify = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.Classify.setObjectName("Classify")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Classify)
        #########################################################
        self.Classify.setEnabled(False)
        self.Classify.clicked.connect(self.Classify_Image)
        #########################################################
        self.Save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.Save.setObjectName("Save")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Save)
        #########################################################
        self.Save.setEnabled(False)
        self.Save.clicked.connect(self.Save_Result)
        #########################################################
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.Log = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.Log.setObjectName("Log")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Log)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Classifier"))
        self.Load.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load"))
        self.Classify.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Classify"))
        self.Save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
    def Load_Image(self):
        app.processEvents()
        self.Log.clear()
        #self.Save.setEnabled(False)
        #self.Classify.setEnabled(False)
        self.Log.append("Loading The Image...")
        # open the image file and convert to grayscale
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        image, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image file", "", "Image Files (*.jpg)", options=options)
        image = Image.open('C:/Users/Armin/Desktop/RCDAT/Apps/First App/image.jpg').convert('L')
        self.Log.append("\nThe Image Is Loaded Successfully...")
        # convert the image to a NumPy array
        image_array = np.array(image)
        image_array = image_array.astype('float32') / 255.0
        image_array = image_array.reshape(1,28,28,1)
        self.image_array = image_array
        self.Classify.setEnabled(True)
        return image_array
    def Classify_Image(self):
        app.processEvents()
        image_array = self.image_array
        #path_saved_model  = 'C:/Users/Armin/Desktop/RCDAT/Apps/Second App/Saved Model.h5'
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        file_name_model, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select saved model file", "", "Model Files (*.h5)", options=options)
        saved_model = load_model(file_name_model,compile=False)
        self.Log.append("\nThe Model Is Loaded Completely...")
        predict = saved_model.predict(image_array)
        Class = predict.argmax(axis=-1)
        Probability = predict[0][predict.argmax(axis=-1)]
        self.Save.setEnabled(True)
        self.Log.append("\nNow You Can Save The Results...")
        self.Class = Class
        self.Probability = Probability
        return Class,Probability
    def Save_Result(self):
        Class = self.Class
        Probability = self.Probability
        np.save('C:/Users/Armin/Desktop/RCDAT/Apps/Second App/Class.npy', Class)
        np.save('C:/Users/Armin/Desktop/RCDAT/Apps/Second App/Probability.npy', Probability)
        self.Log.append("\nThe Results Are Saved Successfully...")
        self.Save.setEnabled(False)
        self.Log.append("\nYou May Use The Classify Button To Classify Another Time...")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I suppose the problem is somehow related to the load_model function in Keras, but I have no idea how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to run the exe in a command prompt?

Comment: @ musicamante
 No, I didn't. Can it help?

Comment: Don't ask it, do it.

Comment: @musicamante I run the exe in the CMD. The process repeated again. Also I did not see anything related to the warnings or errors on the CMD.

Comment: @musicamante
I Used the command below to pack my app: pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Second_App_Test.py

Comment: That's explained in the [pyinstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#getting-debug-messages): "Normally the debug progress messages go to standard output. If the --windowed option is used when bundling a Windows app, they are sent to any attached debugger.". Rebuild it without the `--windowed` flag and see the output. Also, read the whole documentation linked above.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your time. By packaging the app without the --windowed The app works fine, and it does not crash anymore. I received just one warning in the pop-up, which is: WARNING: TensorFlow:AutoGraph is not available in this environment.
In order to packaging the app without running the cmd on the background, how can I solve the mentioned problem?

Comment: I don't know what could cause the issue and I cannot help you there as I don't use neither pyinstaller or TensorFlow libraries. That said, be aware that you shall *not* edit pyuic generated files (read how to properly [use Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)). Also, only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not variables or functions. Finally, if you want to distribute your package, you certainly cannot use hardcoded absolute paths, as they would probably be unavailable, raising exceptions and making your program crash.

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge. Do you believe that changing the packaging library will resolve the problem? What additional libraries did you pick to package your own pyqt code, and which one do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @musicamante for his informative comments, I packaged the app using the Pyinstall command `pyinstaller --onefile Second_App_Test.py`. Now I have cmd on my background while running the app. I noticed that I got a warning and verbosity which is related to the `model.predict()` function in Tensorflow printed out. By changing the verbosity to `verbose=0` inside the `model.predict()` function, the problem solved, and the app in executable mode did not crash anymore.